# é correto armazenar um registro para usar durante o ciclo de vida do processo em uma variável de sessão?

Tags: php, session

Bom dia, eu tenho um sistema web, mas ele está super falho... eu armazeno ID's em input hidden, porém, ele fica visível se inspecionar elemento..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

se eu trocar o id_agendamento para 1, ele irá atualizar o registro 1 ao invés do 26..

seria a melhor forma armazenar esse ID numa session (PHP) e depois recupera-la durante o ciclo de vida do processo? Ou existe alguma outra forma?

**Não sei se a pergunta é duplicada. Tentei ser o mais claro possível. 
Agradeço desde já quem puder me ajudar.**

Comment: SESSION é uma das formas possíveis, assim como LocalStorage ou COOKIES, mas não diria a melhor porque depende do conteúdo armazenado, uma vez que o ID seja algo de importância grande, poderia criptografar e salvar criptografado, mas é melhor que o input hidden

Comment: Não vejo problema que os id fiquem escondidos e possam ser facilmente modificados, o usuário que mudar o valor de 26 para 1 não tem permissão de modificar o 1, retorne um erro do servidor, se tiver permissão deixe fazer a operação normalmente. Na verdade não é tão incomum, o próprio stackoverflow deixa um código  (imagino eu que seja algo semelhante ao id ou o próprio) na url

Comment: Se você colocar um id criptografado no agendamento, dificilmente alguém irá conseguir adivinhar o id certo. Por exemplo: `id_paciente: ushu23hdy4323232` `id_usuario: kjashah8732.uji`

Comment: Na minha visão, essa é a melhor forma (criptografar), visto que ids em sessão também podem ser recuperados e modificados. Além disso usar sessão para armazenamento de muitos dados não é a melhor opção pois cada sessão aberta gera um valor serializado. Para gerar esse valor, você tem um custo e para converte-lo, você tem um outro custo. Imagina isso para muitos dados e muitos usuários...

Comment: Já ouviu falar sobre UUID? Recomendo a leitura https://medium.com/trainingcenter/o-que-%C3%A9-uuid-porque-us%C3%A1-lo-ad7a66644a2b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que a forma mais prática e menos custosa seria você criar uma coluna de chave única na sua tabela do banco de dados, varchar mesmo, para armazenar um segundo identificador. Este segundo identificador deve ser randômico e de mão única, ou seja, sem conversão.

Existem diversas formas de criar uma "hash", por exemplo:

```
//random_bytes dará uma sequência de bytes
//bin2hex converte para ASCII
//sha1 criptografa
$uniq = sha1(bin2hex(random_bytes(32)));
```

armazena esse valor junto com o restante dos outros dados.

Valide também a necessidade de ter o "id_agendamento" e "id_paciente" no formulário. Se o banco estiver bem estruturado e relacionado, você consegue atualizar os dados utilizando somente um único identificador.

No fim, seu input ficará assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="a72e2e0d24022f7c8e34532208ee0b119cb77850">
```

Dessa forma você diminui e muito a probabilidade de alguém acertar o próximo valor.